# Custom HTTPClient for VEGA data url

Tags: angular, keycloak, vega

I'm using VEGA (visualization grammar) in my angular project. Recently I have added Keycloak library in order to have users authenticated.

The Keycloak library has an HTTP Interceptor that adds for each HTTP call the `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` header. The problem is that for the HTTP calls from vega it doesn't.

```
{
$schema: "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
description: "AVGCallDuration Per Total",
width: 720,
height: 520,
autosize: "fit",
signals: [{ name: "timeunit", value: ["day"] }],
data: [
    {
        name: "mainDS",
        url: "https://my-backend-server:8080/api/populations/chart"
}]
}
```

Having the above specification, vega would make a request to `https://my-backend-server:8080/api/populations/chart`. How can I make angular to add `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` header to this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom loader and set it when you create the Vega view. See https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_loader for the docs.

Answer (score 1):

So as @dominik specified, the answer is to use a custom loader. This is what I've come up with after spending some hours looking into this.

Override the default http property of the loader like this:

```
this.vegaView.loader().http = this.vegaHTTPLoader.bind(this);
```

Write your function like this:

```
vegaHTTPLoader(url, options): Promise<string> {
    const _self = this;
    const httpCallOptions = Object.assign({}, { headers: {'header1':'value1','header2':'value2'}, responseType: 'text' }, options);
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        _self.httpClient.get<string>(url, httpCallOptions).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                resolve("" + response);
            },
            (error) => {
                reject("Error while loading the URL provided as datasource for this vega chart. " + error);
            }
        );
    });
}
```